# Prevent Visual Studio from leaking pdb path in compiled exe

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, assemblies, pdb

When I build my C# project as a release in Visual Studio, the resulting .exe contains the following string:

```
C:\Users\jornane\source\repos\«solution»\«project»\obj\Release\«name».pdb
```

The .exe file leaks my username and the path where I store the project.  Is there a way I can prevent this from happening?  I understand why that path would be there for Debug builds, but not for Release.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to replace the stored PDB paths using the [`-pathmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/pathmap-compiler-option) compiler option, for example the following generates `«name».exe` with the PDB path stored as `.\«name».pdb`, instead of using the full path.

```
C:\Users\«user»\source\repos\«solution»\«project»>csc -debug -pathmap:"%cd%=." «name».cs
```

The `-pathmap` option is not exposed in the IDE, but can be set into the `.csproj` file directly, by adding the following near the end of the file.

```
<Project>
<!-- ... -->
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- after 'Microsoft.CSharp.targets' for 'IntermediateOutputPath' to be defined -->
    <PathMap>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(IntermediateOutputPath)=.</PathMap>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Replace `<PathMap>` with `<PathMap Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">` for the option to apply to release build(s), only.

*Note*: the replacement path is set to `"."` in the examples above because `csc` does not allow it to be empty (`error CS8101: The pathmap option was incorrectly formatted`). Any other non-empty user-defined string will work in place of `.` as well.

Comment: C/C++ builds can use the [/pdbAltPath:%_pdb%](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/pdbaltpath-use-alternate-pdb-path?view=vs-2019) linker switch to remove the PDB path from the target EXE or DLL.